# Android retrofit missing fields in the POJO

Tags: android, json, api, networking, retrofit

I am using Retrofit to get the data from the API and parse it into a POJO object.

However, the API is not documented and I am not very sure what data does the JSON contain.

I have field in my POJO for the data I am sure is coming, but at times they are fields in the JSON that I have not accounted for.

Obviously, Retrofit just ignores these fields.

How can I make it send a warning when a field in the JSON is NOT in the POJO?

```
class User { 
    @SerializedName("id")
    private Integer id;

    @SerializedName("name")
    private String name;

    [relevant getters and setters]
}
```

The JSON that is coming is:

```
{
    id: 5,
    name: "John",
    age: 23
}
```

Age field is not in the POJO, but at application does not throw any error; how do I make it display an error in such instances?

Answer (score 0):

You may consider using  Jackson to deserialize your POJO.

Then you can use the following [annotations](https://fasterxml.github.io/jackson-annotations/javadoc/2.6/com/fasterxml/jackson/annotation/JsonIgnoreProperties.html#ignoreUnknown()):

```
@JsonIgnoreProperties(ignoreUnknown = false)
```